# Swift - Pass variable from an extension to view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble passing a value out of my view controller extension to the view controller calling the method. I don't want to return anything out of the function due to asynchronous network call. I tried `(UIViewController() as! FrontPageViewController).nextPageToken = nextPageToken` to no avail. I looked around and can't find a solution for this, thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like your looking for `self.nextPageToken` but it's hard to tell without a more complete example of what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Basically I have an UIViewController extension where I am populating some JSON data. I want to pass a string variable to the main view controller that called the fetchData method inside the extension. The `nextPageToken` is that property in the view controller, and also happens to be the name of the variable inside the extension.

Comment: That makes sense but I'm afraid doesn't tell me much about where you might be confused or having trouble. Can you create a minimal code example? Calling `UIViewController()` instantiates a new view controller which is not a `FrontPageViewController` and seems far enough from what you are trying to do that I suspect some fundamental confusion.

Comment: I am trying to get the instance of the view controller (FrontPageViewController) that is already initialized which is calling the method in the extension. I just want to pass the string variable (nextPageToken) from this extension to the existing instance of FrontPageViewController. I am unsure how to do this obviously, thanks again!

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be using an extension anyway, but have you considered using a completion handler for the method? This would allow it to be asynchronous and allow the calling view controller to handle the response.

Comment: Thanks PEEJWEEJ, I forgot about a completion handler, this works well and is what I'm looking for. Thanks!